# CSS text indent not working on IE7

Tags: css, text-indent

Here is the sample page: http://jsfiddle.net/p9Fbb/

Basically, when using `text-indent` on the icon, Internet Explorer 7 (IE9 in Compatibility Mode) moves the element off-screen, not just the text. For some reason, this only happens in certain circumstances in table cells (I think it's when the element is on its own in a cell).

How can I fix this? Or is there another way to use textual content in an element but keep it invisible?

Comment: works fine for me in ie8: http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/p9Fbb/3/

Comment: Don't you mean IE7 instead of IE8?

Comment: @NGLN @Jason: Technically it is IE9 with Compatibility Mode on, which I assumed was IE8 equivalent, but it could easily be IE7.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that the problem is that your span become *empty* (or it's size become 0 **(not sure)**)  after the text-indent, ence it's not displayed. Put text around your span, you'll see it's still there.

see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p9Fbb/9/) for an example.

use `display:block` instead of `display:inline-block`. Inline-element do not like size declaration much (width/height), they are made to be *displayed inside something*, taking room *according to their content*.